# Clone a Laravel Project

Tags: laravel-5

what is the best way to use an exist laravel project to create a new project.I copied my project floder  and I renamed it but it does not work

Please, somebody help me!

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to install the dependencies through composer as well as any node dependencies you have.

Run `composer update` on the new project.

Also make sure your file permissions are correct on the new project.

Comment: i should create a new project and copy all files of my exist project in the floder of new project or just copy floder and rename it and run composer update on the copy ??

Comment: If you have duplicated all files including the vendor directory you will not have to run `composer update` and it is most likely it will be a file permissions issue.

Comment: My problem is that I want to create a project independent of the project that I had copied but even if I had renamed they are related. PS: I am a beginner in laravel

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to do this is Version Control System.

Step 1: Create Repo of your existing project
Step 2: Fork your Repo, this will allow to choose another project name and so on

You will be able to use your first Repo as template any time when you will need without copy/paste of files on your local